# Set Dynamic Id using JS using Counter

Tags: javascript, html, sfdc

I am trying to dynamically set a cell id using a cnt counter variable. However, instead of a number, I get the cnt word when viewing page source in browser.

What is wrong

```
 q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('id', `q1TargetVolume-${cnt}`);
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/uhmay5hx/). Please show a [mcve].

Comment: dataRowCell4 = dataRow.insertCell(2);
              q1TargetVolume = document.createElement("input");          
              q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('type', 'text');
              q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('maxlength', '8');
              q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('size', '4');   
              q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('id', `q1TargetVolume-${cnt}`);  
     q1TargetVolume.setAttribute('value', record.get('q1_target_volume__c'));
              dataRowCell4.appendChild(q1TargetVolume);

Comment: in my code, there are ticks which are removed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wish to append a count value to the string `q1TargetVolume-`, and use it as the id for an element. You can try this method.

```
q1TargetVolume.setAttribute( 'id', 'q1TargetVolume-' + cnt );//cnt is the count value you wish to append
```

Comment: I tried that but if I look at the page source in the browser I will only see the cnt variable name and not the vaalue in the variable. Very fustrating

Comment: Actually, it is working. I checked the values using the developer tools in Chrome. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Looking for a link. Ok just got it